# How can I roll up a plane like paper?

Tags: unity, shaders, vertex

[image]

Hello, I want to twist the plane. The plane looks like this when I try to do it the way I linked below.

How can I my plane roll like photos?

[How can I roll up a plane with a vertex shader?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151904/how-can-i-roll-up-a-plane-with-a-vertex-shader)

you can see DMGregory answer in this link. I create new shader and paste this code. When I put my mat. to plane. It looks like this.
(Sorry for my bad english.)

[image]

Comment: The beginning of that answer describes the assumptions for how the geometry should be set up to use that shader. How have you set up your geometry to fit that description?

Comment: @DMGregory You said in comment, you used 10x10 plane. I just copy-paste your shader code to in my shader.

Comment: What I said was this: "Those are planes you see in my gif (about 8 of them stacked end-to-end: I dumped their vertices into world space then transformed them from there for a quick demo, rather than making a custom long ribbon mesh myself)" - you are not making a quick demo, so don't do it that way. Make proper geometry according to the first part of the answer.

Comment: @DMGregory I see, but you said too. In seconds video. You have one piece plane. Like mine.

Comment: Yes, for the purpose of demonstrating that the math works on it, but that there are not enough polygons to get a tight roll. That demo served its purpose. Your purpose is different. You're not making a quick demo to prove that it's possible, you want to actually use this as a game asset. So build the right mesh to serve that game asset.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of the [other question linked in the post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151904/how-can-i-roll-up-a-plane-with-a-vertex-shader). As written, I don't see anything that differentiates the two. If I'm mistaken & they *are* different, please edit your post to clarify *how* this question is different than the other one.