# How to unfold a spiral of balls?

Tags: unity, trigonometry

I have a spiral made of balls. It's a spiral with equally distributed balls using the following formula (see [link on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2335190)).

[image]

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Now, the spiral is rolling forward with some speed `forwardSpeed`.

I want to unfold the balls on the ground so they are placed one after another so I have to somehow synchronize the rotation speed of the spiral and the timing of the 'undocking' part of the individual balls.

To make it super clear, I just want the spiral to create a "trail" of balls behind itself.

I've tried various approaches including triggers on the ground so the balls stick to it or even
calculating the distance from "previous ball drop" and if the distance is higher than some threshold then I'd drop another ball.

But these approaches didn't work well and also seemed quite bad.

I want to do it with proper math so I will sleep well made sure that it will work with every possible spiral size.

To calculate the Y position of the spiral on the ground I do a little trick:

```
var spiralRadius = Mathf.Abs(firstBall.position.y - lastBall.position.y); // first and last balls connected to the spiral
```

and then I use it to set the `Y position` of the spiral in `Update()`.
This works pretty well for removing balls from the tail - the Y position is adjusted accordingly so the spiral is always on the ground:

```
yPositionOffset.transform.position = new Vector3(0f, spiralRadius, 0f); // in Update
```

Ok now back to the problem

I have smth like this:

```
private float GetCircumference(float r)
{
    return 2f * 3.1415f * r;
}

void Update()
{
    float spiralHeight = GetSpiralHeight();

    this.rotationWrapper.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(3.1415f * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f));

    // SAND_BALL_DIAMETER is the scale of the ball
    float ballUndockInterval = SAND_BALL_DIAMETER / (spiralHeight * 3.1415f);

    if (Time.time > nextBallUndock)
    {
        nextBallUndock = Time.time + ballUndockInterval;
        UndockBallFromTail();
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    var forwardTranslation = forwardSpeed * Vector3.forward * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    targetPos += forwardTranslation;
    var finalPos = Vector3.Lerp(rb.position, targetPos, Time.fixedDeltaTime * SpeedLerp);
    rb.MovePosition(finalPos);
}
```

And here's the result I get which looks like one of the trigonometric functions... what the hell?

[image]

Does anybody have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: I would approach this problem from the opposite direction. The end result will be a line of balls. I know the distance between them, so the total length of that line is known. That means I know exactly where each ball needs to be and at which point in time it needs to be there. So determining which balls are in the spiral and which are on their designated position on the line is trivial to achieve just through linear interpolation between start position and end position. When I got that working, then I can calculate the rotation of the spiral to match with the line.

Comment: [I did something equivalent to this in a vertex shader recently](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/181380/39518) - you can think of each vertex as one bead on the thread. That might give you some leads.

Comment: I saw that DMGregory. Unfortunately, we need full control of the individual balls + an ability to move the spiral left and right when it rolls.

Phillip, we've tried that and this works for a circle, but not for a spiral.
The results we get are super weird.

Idk I give up, we'll think on faking it somehow